# Is finding boundary-reducing discs for PL 3-manifolds with boundary pattern computationally efficient?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, computational-topology, pl-manifolds

I am working with manifolds with boundary pattern, as defined by Matveev in his book [Algorithmic Topology and Classification of 3-Manifolds](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-45899-9). A manifold with boundary pattern is a pair $(M, P)$ where $M$ is a piecewise-linear ("PL") 3-manifold, and $P$ is a 1-dimensional sub-complex of $\partial M$. I am interested in algorithmically detecting when such an $(M,P)$ is "Haken", in Matveev's sense. This includes three properties: being sufficiently large, being irreducible, and being $\partial$-irreducible. Let us forget "sufficiently large" - it is not a problem in my setting.

Irreducibility for such an $(M,P)$ simply means irreducibility of $M$ in the classical sense: each embedded $2$-sphere in $M$ bounds a $3$-ball. I have very limited knowledge about computational topology, but browsing through the [feature list of Regina](https://regina-normal.github.io/docs/featureset.html), I understand that if I feed Regina my $3$-manifold $M$, it can tell me whether $M$ is reducible, and in that case, produce a reducing sphere. So, besides Matveev showing that there exists an algorithm for reducibility testing, such an algorithm can and has been implemented in practice, rather than being just a theoretical procedure whose runtime would quickly explode.

Now, a manifold with boundary pattern $(M,P)$ is $\partial$-irreducible if for every properly embedded disc $D$ in $M$ disjoint from $P$, the boundary $\partial D$ cuts off a disk of $\partial M$ that is also disjoint from $P$. Matveev's book proves that there is an algorithm for testing $\partial$-reducibility and finding reducing disks. My question is: does anyone know if such an algorithm has been implemented? This might be a bit too optimistic, since manifolds with boundary pattern are perhaps not very popular. I would also be happy if someone familiar enough with Matveev's work and the implementation of such methods could give me an educated guess as to whether this would be technically feasible.

The reason I am interested in these questions is that my colleagues and I are trying to describe an algorithm that involves finding reducing spheres and disks for certain manifolds with boundary pattern. Those steps are being outsourced to the work of Matveev, but we are curious to know what chances our algorithm has of being implemented in practice.

Thanks in advance.